# PhoneGap wrappimg around an existing WebSite

Tags: android, html, cordova

**Enviroment:**
  1. Android 4.0.3
  2. PhoneGap 2.9.0
  3. HTML5

**Use-case**
  1. An existing WWW Web Site
  2. PhoneGap application having it's "super.loadUrl" set to the WWW URL ( not local FS )
  3. Javascript detects when running as an app
  4. Extended App functionality is executed by the WebSite, eg. specialized video capture 
Activity usage

**Problems:**
When lunching the WebSite as in PhoneGap framework I try to load cordova.js:
(  ), Unfortunately, this cause a security exception.

What is the best approach to support the above mentioned use-case ?

Comment: If you are having problems with a specific error message or have a specific question then please provide more information.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that Cordova/PhoneGap was not written to allow you to turn websites into apps - the site will probably look and behave poorly. It's best to use a "mobile first" strategy and design your mobile presence either first or separately from the website. You'll probably be spending a lot of effort redesigning and tweaking your website to work with Cordova when it'd be better to just spend the effort to build the web application from scratch.

If you insist on doing it the way you describe (loading the website immediately by changing the `super.loadURL()` - btw, you should not be changing `super.loadURL()` but instead changing the `<content src="">` tag in `/res/xml/Config.xml`), then you'll probably have to upgrade to the latest Cordova to pick up [some fixes](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-5671) that will help you load cordova.js over the wire.

Comment: I just tried what I said above and while it's easy to get DeviceReady() to fire, it's a little more difficult to get plugin code to load correctly.

Answer (score 0):

From InAppBrowser documentation:

"NOTE: The InAppBrowser window behaves like a standard web browser, and can't access Cordova APIs."

Maybe you can use an iframe to load your website from a local html document that actually loads cordova.js locally.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/16660136/3429223 for reference, should it help.

Best.

---

EDIT:

Totally agree with MBillau's answer. Trying to load an external website as a Phonegap/Cordova app is not an orthodox use case, that may arise several security concerns. Best approach is to design specific version for the app.

Comment: Using an iframe to load external content directly into your cordova app is *not recommend* for security reasons: https://wiki.apache.org/cordova/BugtraqResonseDraft